# Meaning of degenerate PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to understand the concept of degenerate PDE. The definitions I found depend on the type of equation but let say for elliptic ([see here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Degenerate_elliptic_equation)). Let's take an example:
$$x\partial_x^4u + \partial_y^4u + \partial_z^4 + u_x = 0 \qquad (1)$$
then $(1)$ is degenerate if $\exists \xi\in\mathbb R^3, \xi\neq 0$ such that
$$\sum_{\lvert \alpha \rvert = 4} \frac{\partial F(x,Du)}{\partial q_\alpha}\xi^\alpha=0.$$
So I have two questions:

1. I don't understand the definition of the polynomial (what is $\frac{\partial}{\partial q_\alpha}$?), could someone explain how to apply it to equation $(1)$?
2. What does it imply that an equation is degenerate? I have seen that the usual theory does not apply, but what parts exactly? Does it have consequences on the numerical solution?

Comment: Is it $∂_{x^4}$ or $∂_x^4$?

Comment: Fourth derivative w.r.t. $x$ so $\partial_x^4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your equation is linear, and the definition of degenerate you cite is for a nonlinear PDE.

So let's start with linear: A linear pde on a domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is of the form
$$ \sum_{|\alpha|\le k} A_\alpha(x)\partial^\alpha u f. $$
Its principal symbol is defined to be
$$
\sigma(x,\xi) = \sum_{|\alpha|=k} A_\alpha(x)\xi^\alpha
$$
The PDE is elliptic if $\sigma(x,\xi) > 0$ for all $x$ and nonzero $\xi$. It is degenerate elliptic if $\sigma(x,\xi) \ge 0$ for all $x$ and $\xi$. You can use this definition to verify that your question is in fact degenerate elliptic.

A nonlinear PDE is of the form
$$ F(x,\partial^\alpha u) = 0 $$
In other words, it is given by a function $F(x,q^\alpha)$, where you set $q^\alpha = \partial^\alpha u$.
Its linearization at a function $u$ is defined to be the linear differential operator (acting on $v$)
$$ F'(x,\partial^\alpha u)(v) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}F(x,\partial^\alpha (u+tv))\right|_{t=0} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial q^\alpha}(x,\partial^\alpha u)\partial^\alpha v $$
The nonlinear PDE $F(x,\partial^\alpha u)$ is said to be (degenerate) elliptic at $u$, if the linearized operator is (degenerate) elliptic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One more thing: is there anything to know about the qualitative behavior of solutions to degenerate equations? Does it mean that they "change behavior" somewhere in the space, or might change behavior for certain values?

Comment: @Rem, if a differential operator $P$ is elliptic, then the general fact is that any solution to $Pu = 0$ is smooth. If $P$ is degenerate elliptic, then a solution will be smooth in a neighborhood of any $x$, where the symbol $\sigma(x,\xi) > 0$ for all $\xi \ne 0$. However, the solution might not be smooth in any neighborhood of a point $x$ where the symbol is degenerate.

Comment: Thank you, that answers it well.